# Link files from html using fastapi and jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2, fastapi, uvicorn

Hi I'm trying to link to an json file from html code using fastapi and jinja2 but the link is not working. I guess i have to tell fastapi how to find the file or something like that.. I get an json (api) answer instad of the file..

```
{"detail":"Not Found"}
```

The python code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Form, Request
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

app = FastAPI()

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory='templates')


@app.get('/data', response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def data(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse('data.html', {
        'request': request
    })
```

And the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
        <title>Data</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="ui container">
            <h1>
                Data downloader:
            </h1>
            <a href="../json/data.json" target="_blank">
                Data
            </a>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would bet the `href` is wrong. If it's a path to a route, you don't need the `..`, the same if the `data.json` file is in the same folder

Comment: @lsabi No... The path is correct and the url that opens in the new tab is the path where the data.json is located.. If I run the html directly without using fastapi and uvicorn the lik works... So it must be in the fastapi module i have missed something..

Comment: Try sharing your folder structure. Fastapi may be serving only a certain folder as static and the rest pass it through the internal routers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code did it..

python:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Form, Request
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
app = FastAPI()
app.mount("/json", StaticFiles(directory="json"), name="json")

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory='templates')


@app.get('/data', response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def data(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse('data.html', {
        'request': request
    })
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
        <title>Data</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="ui container">
            <h1>
                Data downloader:
            </h1>
            <a href="{{ url_for('json', path='/data.json') }}" target="_blank">
                Data
            </a>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

So it was the import and use of `StaticFiles` that first code dint have